# Windows Phone 8.1 - Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I was just wondering how you deal with IsolatedStorageSettings in Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. For Example:

```c#
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("LocationConsent")
```

How does this work in 8.1? As in, how do I write this statement without getting context errors. I feel like it's been deprecated or something because it does not resolve to a known namespace or anything.

I am working with maps for my current project and porting it to 8.1 gives me some syntax trouble. I have tried looking it up but I think it's too soon for documentation I guess because MSDN doesn't even say anything about it, unless I missed it by accident. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What else are you expecting them to tell you beside that this method returns a boolean ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc614991(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I am wondering how to use that same statement in the new SDK without getting errors. The current one doesn't resolve to a namespace, so it must be deprecated or something, like they changed it.

Comment: I've just tried and it works fine. It's in the System.IO.IsolatedStorage namespace.

Comment: Well the only thing I can use from System.IO is System.IO.Compression.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong on your side, here it works out of the box. That method is located in Assembly System.Windows
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\System.Windows.dll

Comment: @Aybe I know this is a really late response but I should've mentioned when I asked this question that I was using the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK< not the Silverlight 8.1 SDK. I just reopened this question at work, looked at it, and realized my mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the classes in Windows.Storage namespace. They are new for Universal Apps.  If you want the data to stay always local try [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx). However, if you wouldn't mind them been stored in roaming settings (they would be available for your app in Windows 8.1 in case you do Universal Apps) you can use [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700362.aspx).

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if(localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("LocationConsent"))
   DoSomething(localSettings.Values["LocationConsent"])
```

or

```
var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
if(roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("LocationConsent"))
   DoSomething(roamingSettings.Values["LocationConsent"])
```

This should resolve your issue. I wrote this from the top of my head, hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: so there is no necessity of saving the data to the storage? like I used in windows app 8 (i.e roamingSettings.save())?

Comment: you actually need to: ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.SaveSettingValue("key", "value");

Comment: I don't find the SaveSettingsValue() in my code, it's giving me an error.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. I looked over some old piece of code I had and didn't realize I was looking at an extension method. Turns out you don't need to call save. here is the content of the extension method (container is ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings or ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings): container.Values[key] = value;

Comment: oh yes I thought so. Thanks for the help :)