# I can't use IsolatedStorageSettings for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm getting error when I added

```
IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

in my MainPage.xaml.cs for button click event.

**Errors :**

1. The type or namespace name 'IsolatedStorageSettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. The name 'IsolatedStorageSettings' does not exist in the current context

I'm using visual studio ultimate 2013 (update 2).

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 - Isolated Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121146/windows-phone-8-1-isolated-storage)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the classes in `Windows.Storage` namespace. They are new for Universal Apps (Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8.1).

If you want the data to stay always local try [`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx)

However, if you wouldn't mind them been stored in roaming settings (they would be available for your app in Windows 8.1 in case you do Universal Apps) you can use [`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx)

For example,

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if(localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("LocationConsent"))
```

or

```
var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
if(roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("LocationConsent"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i got little bit earlier in msdn forum [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/528844a7-0124-4332-92ca-096514bd477c/i-cant-use-isolatedstoragesettings-for-windows-phone-81] . Anyway thank you bro...