# "Isolated Storage" alternative for Windows Phone 8.1 (not silverlight)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've just upgrade to VS2013 update 2, and found out that WP8.1 now has 2 version: silverlight app ( upgraded from WP8 app) and "windows metro" app , is it true? that's a bit confused @@

And when i tested the new "windows metro" (or "universal" app), I see that this kind of framework doesn't use Isolated Storage ( System.IO.IsolatedStorage) like WP8 app, so any alternative for this ?

Comment: Does this help? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121146/windows-phone-8-1-isolated-storage

Comment: Silverlight apps were deprecated way back when WP8 was introduced. It's not just IsolateStorage that's gone, it's the entire app model.  The equivalent in WP8 is one of the "Windows Phone 8 App" templates. Universal Apps aren't Metro (Windows 8 only) apps. It's a project for creating applications that target both Windows phone and Windows 8, with a common code base and specialization projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ApplicationData.LocalFolder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder)