# Isolated Storage Settings In wp 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

What Can I do In this Case :

"I want to when I close app save (Visible textblock)"

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;



    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        appSettings["name"] = textblock.Visibility;
        textblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

I Use this in windows phone 8.1 (Silverlight)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can Use Isolated Storage in wp 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369679/how-can-use-isolated-storage-in-wp-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

In the app.xaml.cs file you will need to implement some code in the Application_Closing event to retrieve the Visibility property from your page and save it to your ApplicationSettings.

It's called [Tombstoning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx) and is well documented as part of the Windows Phone Application Lifecycle.